# vim / NERDtree / folding - can it remember the state of folds?

Tags: vim, folding, nerdtree

Is there a way to make NERDtree remember the state of folds when switching from buffer to buffer?

Here the my complete .vimrc:

```
set ignorecase
set scs
let perl_fold=1
hi Folded cterm=bold ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=lightblue
set modeline

cabbr N NERDTree
```

Here is what I am observing:

- start NERDTree
- select a file and use spacebar to open it in a new buffer (all folds are closed)
- open some folds in the buffer
- C-w w back to NERDTree
- select a different file, use spacebar to open it
- C-w w back to NERDTree
- select the first file, hit spacebar

The folds I had opened originally are now closed.
I am editing perl files,so the perl_fold=1 is in force.
I'd like the state of the folds to be remembered as I bounce around from file to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure about the `<Space>` mapping? I don't see it listed in NERDTree's help.

Anyway, NERDTree has nothing to do with your buffers content or state, it's only a file explorer.

Without some mechanism to keep state of your buffers your folds are lost when you open a new file. Luckily you can add `set hidden` to your .vimrc.

With it buffers are kept around until you explicitly delete them with `:bd`. This means that you still have your folds when going back to your previous file, either by using NERDTree or by using `:b <Tab>`.

The Vim wiki has [nice](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ) [pages](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching) about buffers.

Comment: Thanks! `set hidden` does the trick. btw - double checked, and space in NERDTree opens the file in the window to the right.